# Authentication in Spring MVC via REST

Tags: spring, rest, authentication, spring-mvc, spring-security

I've been looking for a way to authenticate a user via REST controller (URL params). 
The closest thing to do so is the following:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/api/user")
public class UserController extends BaseJSONController{

    static Logger sLogger = Logger.getLogger(UserController.class);

    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody String login(@RequestParam(value="username") String user, @RequestParam(value="password") String pass) throws JSONException {
        Authentication userAuth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, pass);
        MyCellebriteAuthenticationProvider MCAP = new MyCellebriteAuthenticationProvider();

        if (MCAP.authenticate(userAuth) == null){
            response.put("isOk", false);
        }
        else{
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(userAuth);
            response.put("isOk", true);
            response.put("token", "1234");
        }
        return response.toString();
    }

}
```

However, this doesn't create a cookie.
Any idea or a better way to implement what I want to achieve?

Comment: if your aim is to save the session's information to a cookie based token, you're probably looking for [Remember-Me Authentication](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/remember-me.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, you should not do this manually:

```
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(userAuth)
```

It is better to employ special filter responsible for authentication, setting security context and clearing it after request is handled. By default Spring Security uses thread locals to store security context so if you don't remove it after client invocation, another client can be automatically logged in as someone else. Remember that server threads are often reused for different request by different clients.

Secondly, I would recommend using basic or digest authentication for your RESTful web service. Both are supported by Spring Security. More in docs http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/basic.html

And finally, remember that RESTful web service should be stateless.

Also remember that Spring Security documentation is your friend. :-)

Comment: Thank you, I've moved the authentication to a token based stateless authentication